# PHP Wont print from external API

Tags: php, api

I use to go to school for only a short time in programming. A while ago and I'm rusty. I've been trying to re-learn everything by myself and something is bothering me. I'm trying to print out a specific object from an external API but nothing I try seems to work out. I don't really know what to google to get the right answer I am looking for. Anyway here's my code.

```
    <?php
    $url = 'http://apis.is/flight?language=en&type=departures';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $results = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($results); $x++) {
        echo $results[$x]['results']['flightNumber']."<br/>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are accessing the returned data in the wrong way!

Comment: It's wrong, it's not an array: 
$results = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$results = $results->results; 
should work

Comment: @Mr.bug it IS an array...

Comment: Other way around, @Mr.bug; the second parameter in [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json-decode) is an option for whether to return the result as an array (defaulting to false, which would have it return an object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a **debug** (by the way, learn what is it), you will see, that your `$results` has **one** key: `result`, over which you can iterate with a simple `foreach`:

```
foreach ($results['result'] as $item) {
    echo $item['flightNumber'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the data returned from the API in the wrong order, do this instead:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://apis.is/flight?language=en&type=departures';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$results = json_decode($json, TRUE);
// To loop through an array, use foreach instead of for
// It is easier to use
foreach($results['results'] as $result){
    echo $result['flightNumber'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://apis.is/flight?language=en&type=departures';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$results = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach ($results['results'] as $res) {
     echo $res['flightNumber']."<br/>";
}
?>
```